# Antd table sorting ignores children

Tags: reactjs, sorting, antd

I am trying to sort a table that has children, but it ignores the value "Age" of the children. **All items including children** should sort in Ascending or descending order. Not sure if this is a bug or my implementation is incorrect.

Codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-paper-nvodp

Current Result, Children are ignored. The idea is too sort every item in the tree.

[image]

js:

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: "Name",
    dataIndex: "name",
    key: "name"
  },
  {
    title: "Age",
    dataIndex: "age",
    key: "age",
    width: "12%",
    sorter: {
      compare: (a, b) => a.age - b.age,
      multiple: 3
    }
  },
  {
    title: "Address",
    dataIndex: "address",
    width: "30%",
    key: "address"
  }
];

const data = [
  {
    key: 1,
    name: "John Brown sr.",
    age: 60,
    address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park",
    children: [
      {
        key: 11,
        name: "John Brown",
        age: 42,
        address: "New York No. 2 Lake Park"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    name: "Joe Black",
    age: 22,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park",
    children: [
      {
        key: 10,
        name: "John Brown",
        age: 12,
        address: "New York No. 2 Lake Park"
      }
    ]
  }
];

function onChange(pagination, filters, sorter, extra) {
  console.log("params", extra);
}

function TreeData() {
  return (
    <>
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={data}
        onChange={onChange}
        indentSize={0}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: It is sorting correctly. I added more children to your example, you can see it sorts correctly here: https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-sun-b2bf4

But the children are sorted by age **inside the category they belong too**. If you want the children to be sorted in the same level as the parents... you'll have to think of a different way of signalling which row is a "children row" and which is a "parent row".

Comment: Yes, every item should be sorted in ascending or descending order. I posted a screen shot the current result. It's out of sync with children.

Comment: The table is sorting each item according to its category.

Parents by age = `[22, 61, 62]`.
Children of Yana by age = `[12]`.
Children of Xavier by age = `[10, 30, 40]`.
Children of Warner by age = `[41, 42]`.

Do you want all the children to be sorted together?

Comment: Yes, everything in the tree should be sorted together

Answer (score 0):

You can not resort parent and children in the same tree, so that all elements are sorted by age.

This wouldn't be a tree any longer and does not make sense at all. You would lost the parent - child relation.

If you want to sort all elements by age, you have to move the items into a list and sort them there.

You can only sort the items at the same level and that is what @edo9k 's [implementation](http://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-sun-b2bf4) does correctly!

Tree sorting works as expected by age at for every tree level:

- parents [22, 61, 62]
- children1 [12]
- children2 [10, 30, 40]
- children3
  [41, 42]

Answer (score 0):

Best way you can achieve this through AntD is by using the Nested Tables component. You can display your expandable/children data for each row in your main table into this nested table and then by incorporating the sortable functions in your nested table you can sort that data.